# Async initialization of Promiseified Redis in Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, redis, bluebird, node-redis

I want to do do something like the following

```
const Promise = require('bluebird');
const Redis = require('redis');
const client = Promise.promisifyAll(Redis.createClient(<a-port>, <a-host>));
return client.on_connectASYNC()
.then(() => {
   // initialize some lua scripts
})
```

but the on_connectASYCN never resolves even though adding a callback afterwards does get hit

```
client.on('connect', () => {
    // this gets hit
})
```

I've tried `client.on_readyAsync` and `client.onAsync` as well but they never resolve. Other client calls such as `client.EXPIREATAsync()` resolve as expected.

I'm guessing that there is something about Redis.createClient initialization and/or promisifyAll that I'm really not understanding. Does anyone know why this above doesn't work?

Comment: If you have promisified it, why are you still passing a callback to it? I don't know redis, but I'm pretty sure that code should read `client.on_connectAsync().then(() => {
   /* load some Lua scripts asynchronously */
})
.then(() => {
   /* initialize some more things */
})`

Comment: I've edited it as suggested to make it simpler. The `then()` still does not get entered which is my issue.

Comment: Is `.on_connect(cb)` the same as `on('connect', cb)`?

Comment: ... after looking at the source here https://github.com/NodeRedis/node_redis/blob/39c88206caa8807d7a601c095d3ad60cd31a5a17/index.js#L401 ... no it's not the same. `on_connect` is only called internally by redis and is what fires the 'connect' event. Me calling it via async or not isn't going to have the effect I want. Thanks for forcing me to look deeper. :)

Comment: If `.on('connect', cb)` does what you expect, then use `.onAsync('connect').then(cb)` for promise style.

Comment: `.onAsync('connect')` works as expected. Thanks!